# Use a custom post URL that is outside the blog root directory

Tags: posts, permalinks, url-rewriting

I have a website blog and its URL is:

www.website.com/blog

The above is fine and I want it to stay that way. www.website.com is the main site, which is not a blog.

Currently, the URL structure for a blog post is:

www.website.com/blog/category/post-title-here

Is it possible to make the blog posts have a URL structure like this (so it is not after /blog)?

**www.website.com/category/post-title-here**

Comment: Please have a look at the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You have two options. First, change the folder where your domain goes.

If I get it correctly, now, your domain goes to the root folder. You have to change it, and make it goes to the *blog* folder.

The second option, is move all files that are inside *blog* folder to the *root* folder.

When you did any of these option, you won't be able to access to your wordpress. You'll have to access to it's database, and change the base_url from it.

Here it is explained.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Hope it helps!

Comment: Note: The parent site (not the blog) already lives in the root folder www.website.com so it cannot be moved, and the blog cannot be moved to the root. Basically I'd just like post URLs to _not_ have /blog in them.

Comment: Then, in SEO terms, I strongly recommend you to create a subdomain, blog.yourdamin.com, and make this subdomain goes to your blog folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answear but I'm afraid we can't use a subdomain for the blog the blog home must be under /blog

Comment: Then I'm afraid that you can't hide the /blog term from your URL. Maybe using the .htacces, but I don't how to do it. Good luck